# failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When I run the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'):
    print('GPU is available and configured for TensorFlow')
else:
    print('GPU is not available or not properly configured for TensorFlow')
```

I get the following error:

```
2023-04-17 11:43:09.186983: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:265] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN: unknown error
```

and output:

GPU is not available or not properly configured for TensorFlow

Comment: Please provide us some more details to better understand the issue like `TensorFlow` , `python` version and `system OS` you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To double check, use this [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) to confirm the version dependencies.

Also, there may be an issue in the way NVIDIA driver has been installed.

While doing that , you need to disable secure boot in your BIOS when setting up Ubuntu OS.

Follow these steps :

1. Disable secure boot
2. fresh install ubuntu
3. install cuda toolkit.
4. use tensorflow